# Is it bad practice to using breadcrumbs and subcategories for similar content ?

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

I am building a new navigation system via breadcrumbs based on categories and sub-categories.

Example 1:

```
Having url like this:
http://mywebsite.com/listings-in-london-hatchback-car-for-sale-red-vauxhall

Having breadcrumbs like this:
Home Page > Listings > London > For Sale > Car > Hatchback > Vauxhall > Red
```

That Page has 10 red cars.

Example 2:

```
Having another url like this:
http://mywebsite.com/listings-in-london-hatchback-car-for-sale-vauxhall

Having another breadcrumbs like this:
Home Page > Listings > London > For Sale > Car > Hatchback > Vauxhall
```

That Page has same 10 cars but users may add in the future cars which are not red.

Example 3:

```
Having another url like this:
http://mywebsite.com/listings-in-london-hatchback-car-for-sale

Having another breadcrumbs like this:
Home Page > Listings > London > For Sale > Car > Hatchback
```

That Page has too same 10 cars but users may add in the future cars which are not vauxhall.

There can be similar situations for other categories. Is it bad practice ? Can it be the cause for duplicate content penalty ? What should i do for avoid any penalties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate content issue you are talking about is a filter and not a penalty.

Google will probably think all those pages are the same at the moment because they are so similar. So Google will only display one of them in the search results. The one it thinks is most important.

This is because Google thinks it's not in the users interest to see ten search results that end up showing exactly the same information. So Google filters out those duplicates from specific search results.

Over time the pages will start to become more unique, target different keywords and hopefully end up in the search results based on their own merit and not trample over each other.

Saying that...

Googles Panda update was about weeding out websites that have a high percentage of poor quality pages. If there is too much duplication, especially if other websites are using the same copy, then there is a chance that the website might trigger the Panda!

Another slight negative is that it creates more pages for Google to crawl, meaning it may take more time to discover new or changed pages.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I think it's fine with navigation like that, I doubt any duplicate content penalties could be give, just remove the breadcrumbs on product pages as it can be slightly annoying. Check out a good breadcrumb navigation best practice guide [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/breadcrumb-navigation-examined-best-practices-examples/). 
You can also check out the official 'Duplicate Content Penalty Demystified' guide [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html).

Comment: can you be more open about annoying breadcrumbs on product pages ??

Comment: @motto Oops, yeah sorry, take a look at amazon's website, they do not have breadcrumbs on their product pages because many people find them slightly annoying; possibly due to the fact that it is not required as they should already know the location of the website that they are currently at, and they also clutter up the page, so keep them on the product. The reason navigation is not needed on product pages is because breadcrumbs are used alongside search to locate a product, so using breadcrumbs on a product page is useless as the user has already located the product that they want.

Comment: On the + side for product page breadcrumbs. If you use semantic mark-up then Google may show your breadcrumbs in the search results. it end's up in a neater looking search result that may attract more people to your website. It also lets people go directly to the category page instead of the product (not sure if that is good?)